# SQLite Studio cannot load database - red exclamation marks

Tags: sqlitestudio

SQLite Studio on my Mac suddenly stopped being able to load databases.

1. Launched app and clicked Database | Add a database
2. Red exclamation mark appears on File and Name prompts
3. Browsed to a known good .db3 file, clicked Test Connection and got a green tick.
4. Red exclamation marks still present on File and Name, OK button is disabled, cannot proceed.

This was on SQLite Studio V3.1.x.

Deleted the app, rebooted the Mac, installed V3.2.1, same problem for all of several other known good .db3 files. Cannot see any cache that I could clear.

MacOS version is 10.14.6

Advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was just to re-check Databases on the View menu. Had been accidentally turned off. By the way I see red exclamation marks are normal until you select a file.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved changing the name of the file to charge (in my case there were a conflict with the same file prior charged).